# Can order be better preserved when using the tsort algorithm?

Tags: perl, graph, tree

I'm using the [`tsort` algorithm](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~copeland/work/tsort.html) to sort a list of libraries and their dependencies. Where the dependencies don't prohibit it, I'd like for the sort order to remain unchanged. Such does not happen with this list of libraries:

- this
- that
- other [that]
- thing [that this]

The dependencies are specified in the brackets. `this` and `that` have no dependencies. `other` depends on `that`, and `thing` depends on `that` and `this`. After applying `tsort`, I'd like the list to be output as:

- this
- that
- other
- thing

No change to the order. What I get instead is:

- that
- other
- this
- thing

Which is correct in terms of dependency resolution, but fails to preserve the original order.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use v5.10;

sub sortem {
    my %pairs;  # all pairs ($l, $r)
    my %npred;  # number of predecessors
    my %succ;   # list of successors

    for my $lib (@_) {
        my $name = $lib->[0];
        $pairs{$name} = {};
        $npred{$name} += 0;

        for my $dep (@{ $lib->[1] }) {
            next if exists $pairs{$name}{$dep};
            $pairs{$name}{$dep}++;
            $npred{$dep}++;
            push @{ $succ{$name} } => $dep;
        }
    }

    # create a list of nodes without predecessors
    my @list = grep {!$npred{$_}} keys %npred;
    my @ret;

    while (@list) {
        my $lib = pop @list;
        unshift @ret => $lib;
        foreach my $child (@{$succ{$lib}}) {
            push @list, $child unless --$npred{$child};
        }
    }

    if ( my @cycles = grep { $npred{$_} } @_ ) {
        die "Cycle detected between changes @cycles\n";
    }

    return @ret;
}

say for sortem(
    ['this',  []],
    ['that',  []],
    ['other', [qw(that)]],
    ['thing', [qw(that this)]],
);
```

How can this be modified to preserve the original ordering as much as possible?

For those who don't know Perl but just want to see it at work, paste these lines into a file and feed the file to `tsort` to get the same, non-order-preserving output:

```
that thing
this thing
that other
that this
```

Comment: Oops, thanks for the typo fix, @davido.

Comment: I'm wondering if your topological sort is stable.  It would seem that it is not.  However, in searching on the topic, I find just about no discussions on stable topological sorts.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stable," @DavidO.

Comment: Taking graphs out of it, a "quicksort" is not stable, so there is no assurance that two equivalent elements would retain their order in relation to each other, whereas a "mergesort" is stable.  Imagine sorting `a1 b2 c3 d3 e4` on the 2nd digit only.  A merge sort would preserve "c3 d3", whereas a quicksort may or may not.  Back to graphs: It seems that the algorithm your topological sort is using is not stable, so "c3 d3" could end up as "d3 c3", or as "c3 d3" depending on the weather conditions. ;)

Comment: Well, it emits in exactly the same order every time, it's just not the same as the order in which I originally provided the list.

Comment: Well, by saying "depending on the weather conditions" I was trivializing it a bit.  Even an unstable sort will always produce the same output for a given same input, where "same" means same list size, same starting order, and same elements.  The instability is reproducible, and with a lot of work with a pencil and paper, predictable.  Basically a stable sort guarantees that equal elements will retain their original positions.  Instable sorts don't make that guarantee, but are repeatable.

Answer (score 4):

Let's write your last loop like this:

```
while (my @list = grep { !$npred{$_} } keys %npred) {
  push(@ret, @list);  # we will change this later
  for my $lib (@list) {
    delete $npred{$lib};
    for my $child ( @{ $succ{$ib} } ) {
      $npred{$child}--;
    }
  }
}

if (%npred) {
  ...we have a loop...
}
```

I.e., we making sweeps over `keys %npred` looking for zeros. When the `grep` returns no elements we are either done or have a loop.

To make the topological sort stable w.r.t. some initial ordering, we just change `push(@ret, @list)` to:

```
push(@ret, sort {...} @list);
```

where `{...}` is the comparison function which specifies the initial ordering.

Update with a complete working example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw/pp dd/;

my %deps = (
  # node => [ others pointing to node ]
  this => [],
  that => [],
  other => [qw/that/],
  thing => [qw/that this other/],
  yowza => [qw/that/],
);

# How to interpret %deps as a DAG:
#
# that ---> other ---+
#   |                V
#   +------------> thing
#   |                ^
#   +---> yowza      |
#                    |
# this --------------+
#
# There are two choices for the first node in the topological sort: "this" and "that".
# Once "that' has been chosen, "yowza" and "other" become available.
# Either "yowza" or "thing" will be the last node in any topological sort.

sub tsort {
  my ($deps, $order) = @_;

  # $deps is the DAG
  # $order is the preferred order of the nodes if there is a choice

  # Initialize counts and reverse links.

  my %ord;
  my %count;
  my %rdep;
  my $nnodes = scalar(keys %$deps);
  for (keys %$deps) {
    $count{$_} = 0;
    $rdep{$_} = [];
    $ord{$_} = $nnodes;
  }

  for my $n (keys %$deps) {
    $count{$n}++ for (@{ $deps->{$n} });
    push(@{$rdep{$_}}, $n) for (@{ $deps->{$n} });
  }

  for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$order; $i++) {
    $ord{ $order->[$i] } = $i;
  }

  my @tsort;

  # pp(%$deps);
  # pp(%rdep);

  while (1) {
    # print "counts: ", pp(%count), "\n";
    my @list = grep { $count{$_} == 0 } (keys %count);
    last unless @list;
    my @ord = sort { $ord{$a} <=> $ord{$b} } @list;
    push(@tsort, @ord);
    for my $n (@list) {
      delete $count{$n};
      $count{$_}-- for (@{ $rdep{$n} });
    }
  }

  return @tsort;
}

sub main {
  my @t1 = tsort(\%deps, [qw/this that other thing yowza/]);
  print "t1: ", pp(@t1), "\n";

  my @t2 = tsort(\%deps, [qw/this that yowza other thing/]);
  print "t2: ", pp(@t2), "\n";

  my @t3 = tsort(\%deps, [qw/that this yowza other thing/]);
  print "t3: ", pp(@t3), "\n";
}

main();
```

The output is:

```
t1: ("this", "that", "other", "yowza", "thing")
t2: ("this", "that", "yowza", "other", "thing")
t3: ("that", "this", "yowza", "other", "thing")
```

Comment: That returns `[qw(other thing that this)]`, which is still wrong. I tried using `unshift` instead of `push` and got `[qw(that this other thing)], which has `that` and `this` reversed. :-(

Comment: Ah, wait. I added a an index, `my %ord = do { my $i = 0; map { $_->[0] => $i++ } @_; };`, and then changed the `push` line to `unshift @ret, sort { $ord{$a} <=> $ord{$b} } @list;` And that returns the correct answer. Very interesting. Gonna plug it into the actual code I have and see if it works.

Comment: Sure enough, that seems to [do the trick](https://github.com/theory/sqitch/commit/86b66b048c52326d991bc81e631460ad37228041). Thanks @user5402!

Comment: I'm glad you figured out a solution!

Comment: Uh-oh, does not work with dependency lists of varying lengths. Example: I expect this to output `[qw(this that other thing yowza)]`, but get `[qw(that this other thing yowza)]`, instead: `say for sortem(
    ['this',  []],
    ['that',  []],
    ['other', [qw(that)]],
    ['thing', [qw(that this other)]],
    ['yowza', [qw(that)]],
);
`

Comment: See my updated answer. In your example both `this, that, ...` and `that, this, ...` are valid ways to begin the topological sort. You have to give a preference to one or the other. In my updated response see the difference between runs `t2` and `t3`.

Comment: Thanks. Alas, if I set `%deps` to `my %deps = (
  this => [],
  that => [qw/this/],
  other => [],
);` and call `tsort(\%deps, [qw/this that other/]);`, it returns `[qw(this other that)]` rather than `[qw(this that other)]`.

Comment: Because the solution, unfortunately, is not general enough. See my last comment, in which the order was not preserved. :-(